# Flask SocketIO will not emit data to a specific room

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am creating a program that gets data from a flask app, and can send data to the flask app, and I am using Socket IO to do this.

```
socketio.emit('receive_data', data)
```

this ends up working when sent to this:

```
@sio.on('receive_data')   
def handle_receive_data(data):         
    print('Received data:', data)
```

But when I add a room parameter

```
socketio.emit('receive_data', data, room='my_room')
```

suddenly, the receive data is never even called. This is my complete code for the program:

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.on('connect') 
def on_connect():
    print('Connected to server')
    sio.emit('join_room', 'my_room')

@sio.on('receive_data')
def handle_receive_data(data):
    print('Received data:', data)

sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
sio.wait()
```

and this is my complete code for the flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room

app = Flask(name)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'home'

@app.route('/send')
def send():
    data = {'foo': 'bar'}
    socketio.emit('receive_data', data, room='my_room')
    print('Sent data:', data)return 'sent data'

if name == 'main':
    socketio.run(app, host='localhost', port=5000)`
```

Why will it not receive the data when I add the room parameter?

Answer (score 1):

This emit in your client:

```
sio.emit('join_room', 'my_room')
```

doesn't really do anything. Keep in mind that rooms are all managed on the server, a client cannot join a room directly, it must ask the server to do it. Your server does not have a handler for the `join_room` event, so the emit that you are sending is going to be discarded.

You should add a handler for this event in your server, and in it call the `join_room()` function to put the user in the requested room. Maybe something like this:

```
@socketio.on('join_room')
def on_join_room(room_name):
    join_room(room_name)
```